# How to add another deck to card game as per user's input

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm new to java and I've been trying to create a program that enables you to draw cards from a deck shuffled or ordered.

And now I want to let the user choose the amount of decks. I've tried different ways but cant get it to work.

**The program** (i've added comments as translation since i wrote it in swedish):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KortSpel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean fortsatt = true;        
        while(fortsatt){    

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] deck = new int[52]; 

        String[] suits = {"Spader", "Hjärter", "Ruter", "Köver"};    //the suits
        String[] ranks = {"Ess", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Knäckt", "Drottning", "Kung"}; //the rank of the cards

        for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i;



        System.out.print("Skriv dra för att dra korten annars avsluta."); //ask the user if he want to keep playing or not
        String svar2 = scan.nextLine();

        if (svar2.equalsIgnoreCase("Avsluta")){ 
            fortsatt = false;
            System.out.println("Du har nu avslutat.");  //tells the user he has exit
        }

        else {


            System.out.print("Vill du bland korten? (ja/nej) "); //ask the user if he want to shuffle the cards Y/N
            String svar = scan.nextLine();

            if (svar.equalsIgnoreCase("ja")) {                  // if shuffled

                for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

                    int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
                    int temp = deck[i];
                    deck[i] = deck[index];
                    deck[index] = temp;
                }
                for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
                    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
                    System.out.println("Kort nummer " + deck[i] + ": " + suit + " " + rank);
                }
            }

            else    {                                           //if not suffled

                for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i;

                for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
                String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
                System.out.println("Kort nummer " + deck[i] + ": " + suit + " " + rank);
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use int[][] deck = new int[2][52]; (example for two decks)

Comment: `int[] deck = new int[52*2];` and `for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i%52;`

Comment: how would it be if i instead of the 2 added a variable that holds a number. so the user can choose x amount of decks

Comment: tried both suggestions and none of the worked. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but probably you want to read data from command line during program running.

If yes, then you can use System.console().

```
 Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String deck = c.readLine("Enter additional deck: ");
```

More information you can find here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: Your on the right way, but instead of adding 1 deck I want to let the user choose X amount of decks. For example he can choose 6 decks direct from start.

Comment: @Hevar this actually let's the user choose a number. which you can then choose to create N (chosen number) decks. Also it shouldn't be us to be on the right way, but yourself ;) since it's your homework

Answer (score 0):

To make your application dynamic (1-to-n decks). You have to work on application design before coding. I would suggest you Node style for this. like:

```
class Deck{

    Deck nextDeck;
    Deck periousDeck;

    String[] card1=new String[13];
    String[] card2=new String[13];
    String[] card3=new String[13];
    String[] card4=new String[13];

    Deck(){
        //initialization of cards
    }
}
```

This is your NODE and its little complex too.

Before doing go through manual linked-list [READ](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)